# how to put comma in US currency

Tags: apex

I want to put a comma in US currency by using apex class and method which take Integer as input and give String as output. how can I do that... 
 1000000000=1,000,000,000

Comment: just go through this link https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hmYGAAY

Comment: i want to do this by apex class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of `format` integer function. Try below code in developer console.

```
integer myInt = 1000000000;
system.debug('---------------'+myInt.format());
```

The return type of this is String.

> Edit: You can have a method like this

```
public string formatCur(Integer curVar)
{
    return curVar.format();
}
```

> The user has asked if he can build his own method to format the
>   currency. So, editing the answer again.

Here, I used **RegEx** pattern which will find the right places in the integer and if found the match, replace it with the ','. Please find the code below:

```
public string formatCurr(Integer yourInteger)
{
    string regex = '(\\d)(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))';
    Pattern objPt = Pattern.compile('(\\d)(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))');
    Matcher regMatcher = objPt.matcher(String.valueOf(yourInteger));
    String formattedCur;
    if(regexMatcher.find()) {
        formattedCur = String.valueOf(yourInteger).replaceAll(regex, '$1,');
    }
    return formattedCur;

}
```

And use it like this:

```
system.debug('---------------'+formatCurr(100000));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: A very important note about using the `format()` method is that the result is dependent on the locale of the user. If someone tries to use this in Italy, for example, the output would be `1.000.000.000` because (to the best of my knowledge) all of the European and former Soviet Bloc countries use the preiod/full stop as the decimal grouping (radix) symbol.

Comment: @DerekF: You are absolutely right! Forgot to mention it!

Comment: what if I want to write a class as I mention with a method which takes an integer as input and gives string with comma as  output. can we do this by using any string methods like substring or something else?

Comment: @ajayrawat I didn't quite understand your question. But I edited the answer and added the method. Hope it helps.

Comment: yes, format() is a pre-define method I want to create mine.

Comment: @ajayrawat : I have edited my answer. Please check. Please mark it as answer if it answers your question. Thanks!